# Issue while reading data from XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

I tried to read the data from a XML file. And its working fine with one project. But the same code is not working with other project which  could not figure it out....for the difference as I am using the same code and same XML source file.

With one project, I am able to read the content properly with xrReader.GetAttribute(0) ' Out put example : BANKNIFTY23101244200CE

With other project by using the same code, I am able to get the wrong output data....' Out put example : BANKNIFTY.......44200CE (Date value is getting converted as given.)

I am using the small code for reading content from XML file goes here....

Please help me out on this issue.

```
Using xrReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(source)
Do While xrReader.Read()

If xrReader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element AndAlso xrReader.Name = "Mapping" Then

If xrReader.GetAttribute(0).ToString.StartsWith("BANKNIFTY") Then

BankNiftyMappingPresentExpiryDateTextBox.Text = xrReader.GetAttribute(0)
End If

End If

Loop
End Using
```

Please find out here the sample XML source file for your reference.

```
<Mapping symbol="BANKNIFTY23101244200CE" name="44200CE" exchange="" />
<Mapping symbol="BANKNIFTY23101244200PE" name="44200PE" exchange="" />
<Mapping symbol="BANKNIFTY23101244300CE" name="44300CE" exchange="" />
<Mapping symbol="BANKNIFTY23101244300PE" name="44300PE" exchange="" />
```

Comment: Please add a language tag for the language that you used ([tag:vb]  or [tag:vb.net] ?)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: `BankNiftyMappingPresentExpiryDateTextBox` ????  Please create a [mre], so tell us what that thing is.

Comment: Can you give more details on what's going wrong?  What are you actually getting, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: While reading data from the XML source file, I could get the out in BankNiftyMappingPresentExpiryDateTextBox  as BANKNIFTY23101244200CE with one project. 

But I am using the same code to read the values from same XML file, and getting the value on text box as BANKNIFTY.................44200CE

As I observed, date value is not reading and getting converted into BANKNIFTY.................44200CE.

I could not understand, why the proper value i not getting on other project with the same piece of code from the same XML location. Please guide me on this ussue.

Comment: A valid XML, and some **complete** code, which can be used to reproduce the problem, would be nice.  (Please use [edit] to improve your question)